# Implementing MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack with a WebUserControl

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, url, postback

I have a `WebUserControl` (.ascx) page included in a `WebForm` (.aspx) page.

This `WebUserControl` has a `Button` that upon clicking it, some data will be fetched in HTML form and appended to a `DIV`.

The Appended Data has an ID.

```
<div id="1234">
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do is to let the browser scroll to this newly appended div after fetching the data.

So I added the following in the `Page Load` Method.

```
if (Page.IsPostBack)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "hash", "location.hash = '#" + LastIDField.Text + "';", true);
}
```

Adding `MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="false"` is not allowed in the `WebUserControl`

> Error parsing attribute 'maintainscrollpositiononpostback': Type
>   'System.Web.UI.UserControl' does not have a public property named
>   'maintainscrollpositiononpostback'.

So I added it in the `WebForm` page where this `WebUserControl` is included.

After the `PostBack`, the `URL` is correct, it contains the "#" plus the ID, but the browser is not scrolling to it (tested on Chrome and Firefox), how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement your own get/set property "maintainscrollpositiononpostback" in control's code, this way it will be available as a property outside of control. If it's set to true, execute client-side script to call  Div's `.scrollIntoView()` method to scroll it back into view.

Or if it's a server-side control, like Label, just call its `.focus()` method in your C# code.